# Sitecore item deletes image on save

Tags: image, sitecore, sitecore7, items, sitecore7.2

We have a pretty large website running on sitecore 7.2.
On a couple of items we noticed a certain problem.
Everytime we link a picture to the item and we save it,
the item is saved without the image.

The items are of the same template of 900 other items, so i don't think it's a template problem.

I can link the images on other items without a problem, so i can exclude these too. (i think)

When i search the logs, nothing is found. No ERROR can be found.

Can someone help me in this problem?

### EDIT

After searching in the database for the records, i found these:
[image: DB-image]

Comment: Do you use `Image` field or link images from RTE?

Comment: It's an Image field actually. There are multiple image field on these items, and 1 of them works like it should work, the other two "delete" the image, or so it seems.

Comment: What are the names of those fields? Any special characters in them? Can you try to rename them and see if this makes a change?

Comment: Hi, since it's a live website, and the fields are used in almost every render, it's impossible to just change it. I tried to reproduce the situation on a local version, but this wasn't successful. I can save the same item with the same image. The name of the Field is BannerImage & LeadImage, they do not contain any special character.

Comment: I assume if you link to same image from a different item, all is well?

Comment: Yes, if i link the same image, on the live environment, to another item, all works well

Comment: Ok. I've seen this before. Has the field recently/at some point been shared and is now not or versioned and is now not?

Comment: Hi Mark, 
The field was shared indeed. We changed it to not share-able 2 weeks ago, because other versions of the same item, had to be able to have different images.

Comment: Ok. Your field still has a "ghost" value in shared fields. I will cook a quick answer.

Comment: Nice one @MarkCassidy !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the ghost value out of Sitecore's "shared fields". For the item ID's in question, take a look at the [SharedFields] table in your "master" database.

SELECT * FROM [SharedFields] WHERE [ItemId]='your item id' AND [FieldId]='your field id'

If I am right, you will find values here. If the field is no longer shared, these should be safe to remove.

Always though, when messing directly with the database, backup etc. :)

Comment: Likely, when you get rid of the ghost; your saved image field value will appear.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22457875/how-to-clean-up-after-sitecore-template-shared-setting-was-packaged-and-ins

Comment: Hi @Mark Cassidy, 
Is it correct that the Value field is empty on those fields? I'll put it in Edit in Question

Comment: There should be no row at all. Empty value is correct, from what you wrote. Try putting the string "test" in, as a value. You should now see that as your field value, if you switch to "raw values". Not sure if the Sitecore client would cache this though.